# Sum of bi-dimensional array indices from single index

Tags: arrays, matlab, parfor

I am trying to create a parallel-for loop in MATLAB to fill an `m`x`m` matrix as follows:

```
parfor i = 1 : m^2
     A(i) = sum( x .^ %Sum of indices% );
end
```

If I was doing it without `parfor` I would simply do:

```
for i = 1 : m
     for j = 1 : m
          A(i,j) = sum( x.^(i+j) );
     end
end
```

However unfortunately `parfor` does not allow for other indices within it's body and therefore I cannot do what I'd like to do.

I have tried extracting the sum of the indices by using `ceil(i/3) + mod(i,3)` however this doesn't work, because at `i=3` it gives me `1` instead of `4` as I want.

Does anyone have a better way of extracting the sum of the indices?

Comment: What is `x` in your example? Can you also provide example of 'A'.

Comment: @Marcin `x` is an array of an independent variable from which I need to compute the elements of `A`, which is coefficient matrix for the simultaneous equations required to solve for polynomial least-squares fitting.

Comment: I doubt that a `parfor` is going to speed things up here, actually I fear it will make it slower.. You're better just rewriting it in vectorized manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
   r=sum(  bsxfun(@power, x(:), m+1:2*m  ) ,1);
   c=sum(  bsxfun(@power, x(:), m+1:-1:2 ) ,1);

   A=fliplr(toeplitz(c,r));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  [I,J]=ndgrid(1:m);
  K=I+J;

  A=zeros(m);

  parfor i=1:m^2

   A(i)=sum(x.^(K(i)));

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another vectorized variation:

```
[I,J] = ndgrid(1:m, 1:m);
K = I + J;
A = reshape(sum(bsxfun(@power, x, K(:).')), [m m]);
```